# Splitting a column that contains multiple date formats

Tags: python-2.7, csv, pandas

I have a csv file that contains a column with multiple date formats. I need to split them and get the extracted result in the same format.

```
Wednesday 12 August 2015
Wednesday 12 August 2015
Friday April 1 2016
Friday April 1 2016
5/12/2016
5/12/2016
```

This is the file and i want it in the mm/dd/yy format. My code is as follows:

```
import re
import csv
import pandas as pd
#delimiters = " ", "/"

#f = open('merged_34.csv')
f = open('test3.csv')
df = pd.read_csv('test3.csv')
for item in df['serverDatePrettyFirstAction']:
    if '/' in item:
       newDate.append(item)
    else:
       item = item.split(' ', 1)[1]
       newDate.append(item)
df['newDate'] = newDate
df.to_csv('D:/Python/10.36.202.64/newfile.csv', index = False)
```

And this is what i get:

```
serverDatePrettyFirstAction newDate
Wednesday 12 August 2015    12-Aug-15
Wednesday 12 August 2015    12-Aug-15
Friday April 1 2016         April 1 2016
Friday April 1 2016         April 1 2016
5/12/2016                   5/12/2016
5/12/2016                   5/12/2016
```

Also is there a way to overwrite the values in the same column itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a faster approach would be to use pandas's method [to_datetime()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
In [2]: df
Out[2]:
                       Date
0  Wednesday 12 August 2015
1  Wednesday 12 August 2015
2       Friday April 1 2016
3       Friday April 1 2016
4                 5/12/2016
5                 5/12/2016

In [6]: df['newDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

Result:

```
In [7]: df
Out[7]:
                       Date    newDate
0  Wednesday 12 August 2015 2015-08-12
1  Wednesday 12 August 2015 2015-08-12
2       Friday April 1 2016 2016-04-01
3       Friday April 1 2016 2016-04-01
4                 5/12/2016 2016-05-12
5                 5/12/2016 2016-05-12
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use third party [dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) library as long as your data is not too big.( After all, It guesses format every time)

```
import pandas as pd

from dateutil import parser

df = pd.read_csv('test3.csv')
df['newDate'] = df['serverDatePrettyFirstAction'].apply(parser.parse)
df.to_csv('newfile.csv', index=False, date_format='%Y-%m-%d ')
```

> to overwrite the values in the same column

Use
`df['serverDatePrettyFirstAction']=df['serverDatePrettyFirstAction'].apply(parser.parse)`

Comment: Thanks a load.Its working perfectly. A bit slow with larger data sets though but that's fine. Is there any other approach apart from importing dateutil. Just curious!!